# Is there a way to run rake db:setup on a single table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have a Ruby on rails app, and I modified db/seeds.rb file and I want to push my changes into my database.

is there an option in Rails where I can run `rake db:setup` and modify only that table without clearing all the other ones ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use rake `db:seed` to run the seed file. `rake db:setup` is much more involved, it basically runs all of the following

```
db:create
db:schema:load
db:seed
```